# broken javascript - formatting tools wont fix it. causes previous block of code to break

Tags: javascript

In as much as I would like someone to say "change this line of code to read....", I really would like to know the solution to the problem of Firefox not reporting broken code. This code block is broken and it causes a previous block of code to break.  It's somewhere in the notdupe.live.click function.  I can comment out the entire function and the rest of the code works. I've tried commenting out pieces but can't isolate the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        var SaveDupeGroup = 0;
        var DupeCount = 0;
        var ReInitAnswer = '';
        var RemoveAnswer = '';

        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.StartOver').live('click', function () {
            ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO DELETE ALL temp dupe records AND start over FROM SCRATCH? \nIt may take a couple OF hours.');
            if (ReInitAnswer) {
              // submit the form TO BEGIN re-creating the temp table
              document.forms["dupeIndivs"].submit(); //return true;
            } else {
              alert('canceled');
              return false;
            }
          });
          $('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
              data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
              error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                alert(errorThrown);
              },
              success: function (response1, textStatus, jqXHR)(
              if ($(e.target).is(":checked")) {
                $firstTD = $(this).parent().siblings().first();
                SaveDupeGroup = $firstTD.text();
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'cfc/basic.cfc?method=CheckDupeGroup&returnformat=json',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: 'DupeGroupNumber=' + $firstTD.text(),
                  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error
                    alert(errorThrown);
                  },
                  success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    DupeCount = response.DATA[0];
                    alert('Dupe Group-' + SaveDupeGroup + ' count=' + response.DATA[0]);
                    if (DupeCount) {
                      alert('huh?');
                    } else {
                      RemoveAnswer = confirm('All of the names in this group have been checked.\nDo you want to remove them from the lists?');
                      if (RemoveAnswer) {
                        alert('continued');
                      } else {
                        alert('canceled');
                        return false;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
              })
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: One thing I can tell you is that you have a syntax error in your success callback. `success: function (response1, textStatus, jqXHR)(` that last character should be a { not a (

Comment: http://jshint.com is good for this sort of thing, if you turn off enough of the errors-that-are-really-style-critiques. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Line 26, you have `function()(` should be `function(){` and because of that you're probably going to have to investigate your closing `}`'s

have you tried checking the code with [jshint](http://jshint.com) or [jslint](http://jslint.com)?

Answer (score 2):

You have a SyntaxError.

This...

```
success: function (response1, textStatus, jqXHR)(
```

should be this...

```
success: function (response1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

also the colosing `)` should be `}`.

Not sure why Firefox (Firebug?) doesn't report it.

Comment: shouldn't I expect to see something in the javascript console?

Comment: @user990016: Yes, you should see SyntaxError. I don't have Firebug installed, but the error does show up in the console built into Firefox 10.

Comment: There must be something in about:config turned off.  I don't see it but will research.